# kendo-chart responsive design sizing not using pixels

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I'm attempting to place a kendo chart in a grid footer template.  All is working well.  However, I would like the chart to take the entire width/height of the cell.  The chart appears to require a height/width in pixels (or it will assume one), which doesn't lend itself to a responsive design very well..

Is there a way to do this currently where sizing can be specified in %?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment, but you can monitor [issue #73](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/73) for updates.